# Can not find 'number' in scope in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am following a tutorial so I'm not sure why the code isn't working. The number in Image(self.countries[**number**])
.renderingMode(.original)
is giving me an error "can not find 'number' in scope in SwiftUI". I have tried changing the closing brackets to include this line, but it still doesn't work.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    var countries = ["Estonia", "France", "Germany", "Italy", "Nigeria", "Poland", "Russia", "Spain", "UK", "US"]
    var correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.blue.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            VStack(spacing: 30) {
                VStack{
                    Text("Tap the flag of")
                    foregroundColor(.white)
                    Text(countries[correctAnswer])
                    foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                
                
                ForEach(0..<3) { number in
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    })    }
                        
                                Image(self.countries[**number**])
                                .renderingMode(.original)
                
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
        
            }
            
        }



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please improve your code formatting/indentation. It seems like your use of `number`  is outside of the `ForEach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ForEach` only contains the button, not the `Image` - the `Image` is outside the `ForEach`, so it can't see what `number` is.

[image: ForEach's trailing bracket is right after the Button]

I assume you want the [Button's `label`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/button) to be the `Image` (a.k.a. make the image the button)? You'll need to rebalance your brackets. *Note: in your current code, your button is missing its label.*

```
ForEach(0..<3) { number in
    Button(action: {
        
    }) {
        Image(self.countries[number])
            .renderingMode(.original)
    }
}
```

Full, re-formatted code (Hint: press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> to automatically clean it up):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    var countries = ["Estonia", "France", "Germany", "Italy", "Nigeria", "Poland", "Russia", "Spain", "UK", "US"]
    var correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.blue.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            VStack(spacing: 30) {
                VStack{
                    Text("Tap the flag of")
                    foregroundColor(.white)
                    Text(countries[correctAnswer])
                    foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                
                
                ForEach(0..<3) { number in
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }) {
                        Image(self.countries[number])
                            .renderingMode(.original)
                    }
                }
                
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```